# Dynamically generate AngularJS form with dynamic textboxes generation

Tags: python, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create textboxes as per the user entered values for each block and get the saved information posted as JSON in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "Student1": {
      "college_name": "abc",
      "age": 20,
      "total_courses": 2,
      "course_1_name": "angularjs",
      "course_2_name": "nodejs"
    }
  },
  {
    "Student2": {
      "college_name": "xyz",
      "age": 22,
      "total_courses": 3,
      "course_1_name": "angularjs",
      "course_2_name": "nodejs",
      "course_3_name": "python"
    }
  }
]
```

The angular code will have html code displaying the form as below:

[image]

Now if I click on add more button, this should bring another blank form for user as below just below the above form that is already filled:

[image]

Now when I fill the form and if I enter total courses as 3, it should dynamically display 3 textboxes as below:

[image]

Now when I fill 3 courses name it would appear as below:

[image]

Now form would appear as below:

[image]

Now when user clicks on submit button it should save the information in the JSON format as mentioned below:

```
[
  {
    "Student1": {
      "college_name": "abc",
      "age": 20,
      "total_courses": 2,
      "course_1_name": "angularjs",
      "course_2_name": "nodejs"
    }
  },
  {
    "Student2": {
      "college_name": "xyz",
      "age": 22,
      "total_courses": 3,
      "course_1_name": "angularjs",
      "course_2_name": "nodejs",
      "course_3_name": "python"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: https://github.com/nsonic001/ko-FormGenerator
if you want to use this, I can help you out, This library does exactly what you want. It is written by me,

Comment: @NileshSoni Can you please provide me an example to show me how we can do it as I am a beginner?